guides not aligning to grids
In Adobe Illustrator, I created a square and did these-
Object>path>split into grids.
Then I added guides. Originally, the guides were supposed to be around grids, but for some reason they appeared outside the grids. Sometimes even outside the artboard. I tried to solve the problem by checking alignment, ruler...
So, what caused it and how to solve it?
In the image below, the right side is where I positioned the square. The vertical guides are on the spot. I want the same for horizontal guides (left side).


So, I tried and reproduce your situation with the same results. When the square was below its artboard, vertical grids were created in the artboard and not horizontal grids.
Checking the outline mode (Ctrl + Y on Windows) shows that both the artboard and the square grids are fine, they're not visual artefacts. Also, one can see that:

when the square is under/on top (resp. to the right/left) of the artboard, there are horizontal (resp. vertical) guides that appear inside the artboard;
when the square is outside the artboard but not on its side/bottom/top, there are horizontal (and vertical) guides that appear under/over (and next to) the artboard.

Based on this behavior, grids outside your square are not a bug. They're a functionality of the Split Into Grids function that allows you to position objects in your artboard or directly next/under/on top of it, while maintaining an aligment with the newly created grid.

Just click the Add Guides box when choosing Split into Grid...


You can then extend the guides as needed - In some cases you may need to Unlock Guides (View Menu) first.
